# python yaml.dump запись в yaml с отступом

Tags: python, yaml

Есть блок кода который записывает в yml каждый раз с новой строки

```
with open(skdpu_http_upstreams, 'a') as f:
          templates = yaml.safe_load(config_dict.get('upstream_config'))
          yaml.dump(templates, f, sort_keys=False)

templates - это словарь такого вида(блок)

строка_ru:
  environment: 
  system_id: 
  domains:
    - строка
```

Как сделать, чтобы новый блок добавлялся в файл с новой строки, и отступом в один пробел?

Comment: `f.write("\n\n")` перед `yaml.dump`

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Вот так сработало f.write('   ')  перед yaml.dump